# Can I create a custom condition for an Azure DevOps Server build step that will run the step in a range of time?

Tags: conditional-statements, azure-pipelines-build-task

Currently I have a powershell, post-build script that launches our Selenium tests.  The time of day is checked and if between 6:45 and 8:00 AM, the full test suite runs.  If not, its a normal CI build and only a small subset of tests runs.

We are switching to TestCafe and I have added Build Definition steps to install testcafe, install testcafe-reporter-junit and run the tests.  I's like to move the test runs to regular steps instead of scripted, if possible, but I would need to know if I can condition the full suite test step to only run during the above mentioned time period.  Is that possible with custom conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no condition syntax that deals with dates and time. But you can run a small scripted step to set a variable, then use that variable in the condition.

Comment: Yep, that's what I did yesterday.